# How to target the nth-child of $(this)

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I am trying to target the nth child of an element on hover.

My html is this....

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child1"></div>
     <div class="child2"></div>
     <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```

At the moment, `.child3` is `display:none`, but on hover of `.parent`, I want to apply opacity to everything, and display `.child3` with no opacity over.

So far I have

```
$(".parent").hover(function() {
       $(this:nth-child(3)).show();
});
```

I need to use `$(this)` as my markup is repeated on my page displaying different products. So I want to target just the particular product that I am hovering over.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I know exactly what I want to do, but just can't quite execute it!

Comment: All [jQuery] selectors are strings - not some new magical JavaScript syntax.

Comment: jQuery Docs will give you a lot of idea. [http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can

```
$(this).children(':nth-child(3)').show();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N6BUM/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find`

```
$(this).find('> :nth-child(3)').show();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6cXd/)**

**[JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/childrenv-sfind)** on all the three options.

By the way, if you have other elements than div as the sibling of the target elements and you want to explicitly select the 3rd div then use `nth-of-type`. nth-child will fail in this case as it will consider any other type child too and if it appear before the 3rd one, 3rd div won't be the one selected.

```
$(this).find('> div:nth-of-type(3)').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use as [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j6cXd/5/)

```
$(".parent").hover(function() {

    $('> div:nth-child(3)', this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: `div:nth-child(3)` doesn't make any difference infact, if you want to specifically select div then need to use `div:nth-of-type(3)`. See this failing http://jsfiddle.net/EBDmk/. You can remove div from the beginning.

Comment: yeah! you could also use $(':nth-child(3)', this).toggle(); but what if there are other siblings inside the children.

Comment: nah! That will select the nested ones too. so `('> :nth-child(3)', this)` is enough but for specific type selection need to use `selector:nth-of-type(3)`